# React Native - react-native run-android is not working after bundleRelease

Tags: android, react-native

I am building a react native app. Yesterday i have ran successfully `cd android && ./gradlew bundleRelease`. After that, I have tried to run `react-native run-android` but got this error: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.

How to make it work again normally in debug mode?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed by changing targetSdkVersion:28 to 26 in build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to run `npm start -- --reset-cache` for the Metro Bundler and then in another terminal try to run `react-native run-android`